# How can I move my Explorer in Visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I accidentally moved my explorer to the right. I tried dragging it back but I couldn't. 
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`right click on the explorer's top  -->  move sidebar right`

Answer (score 1):

There is a menu choice to fix this.

```
View --> Move Side Bar Left
```

[image: VS Code Move Side Bar]

Comment: There is nothing like this in the view.

Comment: @ShahidKarimi clearly there was almost 3 years ago when this was answered.

Answer (score 0):

Right now you can only move the Explorer to the right by moving the entire primary sideBar (and everything in it besides the Explorer) to the right and then dragging everything you don't want in the right-side Primary SideBar back to the left, but some views are not draggable like `Run and Debug` and `Extensions` for example).  You cannot drag and drog the Explorer to the Secondary SideBar from the Primary SideBar (or to the Panel for that matter).

But work has begun on making the Explorer freely draggable to other SideBars or the Panel, see [Support moving the explorer with drag and drop](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/173388) and [Commit: Explore making the explorer a moveable view](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/6ee9724963da3a48c48dee97540ed9c5856c26b7).  This would make the whole process of moving just the Explorer much easier.

---

Update: As of vscode v1.76 you can just drag just the Explorer where-ever you want it, to the right-hand side bar or to the Panel or back to the main left-hand side bar.